# How to stop certain words from my search to go directly to a product - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a search bar for my woocommerce products page. Some searches go to archive-product.php and some go to single-product.php. I want to disable the single-product shortcut. I have tried searching my problem on stackoverflow and google but all I get is search filter plugins.

How do I stop my search from going to single products and automatically search on my inventory list page?

To simplify my problem here is how it looks:

When haven't search anything:
[image]

When I search "wheel" :

[image]

When I search "air filter":

[image]

This is my search bar code:

```
<div class="search-wrap">
            <form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <div class="search">
                    <label class="screen-reader-text " for="woocommerce-product-search-field-<?php echo isset( $index ) ? absint( $index ) : 0; ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-<?php echo isset( $index ) ? absint( $index ) : 0; ?>" class="search-field searchTerm" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Search products&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
                    <button type="submit" class="searchButton" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is this the Product Search Field or a specific plugin? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/widgets/product-search-field/

Comment: @wp78de this is product search field done via PHP without any plugins. I have used woocommerce's search example from their own plugin. (but restyled it in my theme)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_redirect_single_search_result', '__return_false' );
```

Tested on fresh install and works.

Comment: Cool, this is similar to my answer I found, but I didn't realize __return_false was a usable filter. That's awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding this into my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_redirect_single_search_result', 'my_remove_search_redirect', 10 );
function my_remove_search_redirect() {
    return false;        
}
```

Answer found here:
https://removewcfeatures.com/disable-woocommerce-single-search-result-redirect/